# Make a quantity selector javascript

Tags: javascript, laravel

H everyone,

I would like to put a quantity selector on a product page, my script was working fine but since I added a feature to remove the stock on the merchant side, my script doesn't work anymore when there is no more stock... I don't see at all how I could solve the problem.

In database, I usually have a stock (in int) and when there is no stock there is a null in database.

Here is my script:

```
if({{ $CurrentProduct->disposable_quantity }} != null) {
                if (newQty > {{ $CurrentProduct->disposable_quantity }}) {
                    $('input[name="quantity"]').val({{ $CurrentProduct -> disposable_quantity }});
                }
            }


if({{ $CurrentProduct->disposable_quantity }} != null) {
                if (inputValue > {{ $CurrentProduct -> disposable_quantity }}) {
                    $('input[name="quantity"]').val({{ $CurrentProduct -> disposable_quantity }});
                }
            }
```

I don't really understand where this is coming from, the fact that I can't increment my quantity when it equals zero.

Comment: I have not used laravel before however I would suggest using a console log and printing out {{ $CurrentProduct->disposable_quantity }} as I think the output is likely an uppercase NULL and you are comparing it to null. which will blow up in javascript. (I am guessing this is a combination of Laravel and javascript)

Comment: It obviously didn't come from there.

Comment: Ok, I may have misunderstood the question then. I assume ```$('input[name="quantity"]')``` updates the quantity server side when a postback happens. But what is ```$('input[name="quantity"]')``` on page load? is it because this value is empty and when the values are not higher than ```{{ $CurrentProduct -> disposable_quantity }}``` it will post back to the server as null?

Not sure I am missing something or there's not enough of the code here to give you an answer.